# Error when running bash command over ssh

Tags: bash, awk, ssh, pid, ps

When trying to run the following command over ssh:

`ssh hostname 'for pid in $(ps -ef | grep "some process" | awk '{print $2}'); do kill -9 $pid; done'`

I get the following error:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: {print
awk: cmd. line:1:       ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

I've tried escaping in different ways but haven't found the correct way - or maybe it's something else?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use `pkill -f "some process"` in this case.

Comment: That won't kill all processes with a certain name, will it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot include single quotes into a single-quoted string, since nothing is interpreted inside, except the single quote that closes the string. You can concatenate the single-quoted strings with `"'"`:

```
ssh host 'for pid in $(ps -ef | grep "some process" | awk '"'"'{print $2}'"'"'); do kill -9 $pid; done'
```

Alternatively, concatenate escaped single quotes (`\'`):

```
ssh host 'for pid in $(ps -ef | grep "some process" | awk '\''{print $2}'\''); do kill -9 $pid; done'
```

See [Strong Quoting](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#strong_quoting).

**The Cause of the Error**

Your command is interpreted as a couple of [`$IFS`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#IFSREF)-separated arguments:

- `for pid in $(ps -ef | grep "some process" | awk {print`
- `}); do kill -9 $pid; done`

There is no `$2` in the strings, since `$2` is interpreted as a shell variable, and the value of this variable in the normal shell context is empty.

Thus, you have sent the following command to the server:

```
for pid in $(ps -ef | grep "some process" | awk {print }); do kill -9 $pid; done
```

If you run this command in a terminal, you will get the same error from AWK.

Comment: As @ymonad pointed in a previous comment above, the **pkill** command would reduce the quoting problem: `ssh host 'pkill -KILL -f "some process"'` ... as long as the text **`some process`** does not include any quotes, of course.